# Retrieve transactions from APM using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, kibana, nest, apm

I have an asp.net core web app application that will write logs using serilog to elasticsearch and also can read the logs from elasticsearch using NEST. I also have it set up where I can use APM for my application. **If I wanted to retrieve the transactions that are in APM using NEST or the transactions on a specific date, is this something possible?** Any advice/tutorial/documentation on this would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to target the `apm-*-transaction` aliase(s)

In Kibana Dev tools

```json
GET apm-*-transaction/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2021-06-04T00:00:00Z",
        "lte": "2021-06-05T00:00:00Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In NEST (change `dynamic` to your document type)

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();
    
var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index("apm-*-transaction")
    .Query(q => q
        .DateRange(dr => dr
            .Field("@timestamp")
            .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-06-04T00:00:00Z")
            .LessThanOrEquals("2021-06-05T00:00:00Z")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your explanation and help!